# boto key.set_contents_from_string() fails with 403 (but aws s3 cp works)

Tags: amazon-s3, boto

When I try to upload a file using `boto` then it fails with `403 Forbidden` and I am wondering what am I missing.

Command line `aws s3 cp foobar s3://bucket-name/topdir/foobar` runs OK and the file does get uploaded.

WITHIN boto, I can list the bucket and retrieve file contents.

The IAM user perms to bucket are set to Put/Get/DeleteObject. I have tried other methods too, like `set_contents_from_file` but they all fail. Python 2.6.8.

Problem I am trying to solve is: read a file from ftp and push to S3. Like:

```
k = boto.s3.key.Key(b)
k.name = 'new-name'
ftp_handle.retrbinary('remote-name', k.set_contents_from_string)
```

Below is my python session. Will appreciate your help.

```
$ python
>>> import boto
>>> conn = boto.connect_s3()
>>> b = conn.get_bucket("bucket-name")
>>> k = boto.s3.key.Key(b)
>>> k.name = "topdir/foobar"
>>> k.set_contents_from_string("hello, world")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/boto-2.32.1-py2.6.egg/boto/s3/key.py", line 1419, in set_contents_from_string
    encrypt_key=encrypt_key)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/boto-2.32.1-py2.6.egg/boto/s3/key.py", line 1286, in set_contents_from_file
    chunked_transfer=chunked_transfer, size=size)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/boto-2.32.1-py2.6.egg/boto/s3/key.py", line 746, in send_file
    chunked_transfer=chunked_transfer, size=size)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/boto-2.32.1-py2.6.egg/boto/s3/key.py", line 944, in _send_file_internal
    query_args=query_args
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/boto-2.32.1-py2.6.egg/boto/s3/connection.py", line 664, in make_request
    retry_handler=retry_handler
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/boto-2.32.1-py2.6.egg/boto/connection.py", line 1053, in make_request
    retry_handler=retry_handler)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/boto-2.32.1-py2.6.egg/boto/connection.py", line 923, in _mexe
    request.body, request.headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/boto-2.32.1-py2.6.egg/boto/s3/key.py", line 880, in sender
    response.status, response.reason, body)
boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>...</RequestId><HostId>...</HostId></Error>
```

The manual I am following is slightly out of sync with the version of boto I have (2.32 versus 2.34): `http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html` So maybe this is really not supported in boto 2.32. But that shouldn't be generating 403, should it?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use connect_to_region instead of s3connect. I had similar issues while uploading files to s3.